# Google Big Query UTC_USEC_TO_DAY / WEEK / MONTH / YEAR

Tags: google-bigquery

is it possible that the UTC_USEC_TO_ functions are now more strict than it was before on the format of the unix_timestamp ?

We see that we must convert the value first by using timestamp_to_usec
and we didnt have to that in the past

on other words 
**This way it used to work and now it doesnt :** 
UTC_USEC_TO_DAY()

**and now - only this way works :**
UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp_to_usec())

Answer (score 4):

UTC_USEC_TO_ are documented as accepting INTEGER, but they used to accept TIMESTAMP at all. However, BigQuery restored this functionality, so UTC_USEC_TO_ should continue to work they used to.